# Setting JSON data to variable and incrementing + printing

Tags: javascript, html, json

So basically, I am pulling numbers and images from a restful API. What I want to do is make an animation of sort that makes the rating count up by 1 every millisecond where the Start is the rating minus 300 and the end is the actual rating. I have some code down there but It doesn't seem to display anything on my site and I probably made a mistake but I am not sure where. Could anyone give me advice or point me in the right direction?

```
<!-- Calls on API, requests current SR -->
<script>
  let requestUrl = "https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/us/ShalevBito-
2753/complete";
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestUrl);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  request.onload = function() {
    logData(request.response);
  }
  function logData(data) {
    document.querySelector('.rating').innerText = `${data['rating']}`;
    document.querySelector('.rank').src = `${data['ratingIcon']}`;
    var start = `${data['rating']}`;
    var counter = `${data['rating']}` - 300;
  }
  if (counter < start) {
    counter++;
  }
</script>

<!-- Displays current SR -->
<p class="counter"</p>
<img class="rank">
```

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't work_".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval will probably help but note that you cannot make that many network requests, no API will allow you to do 1000 requests a second

Comment: Updated question, Im not exactly sure what is wrong with my code though.

Comment: There is no loop here and no callback. This code will execute once.

Comment: See my answer, you need to use setInterval to allow you to repeatedly call the same function. One thing i would advise is to slow down the increment of numbers as a number changing every milisecond will be very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to implement something like this in your code:

You need to use `setInterval` to repeat the function call many times.
Take your counter out of logData (so that it doesnt get reset every time)
Then modify your `logData` to include the `clearInterval` api

```js
   
    var repeater = setInterval(logData, 1, 700);
    
    var start = 700;
    var counter = 700 - 300;

    function logData(data) {
        document.querySelector('.rating').innerText = counter;

        if (counter < start) {
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(repeater);
        }
    }
```

```html
<span class='rating'></span>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what your saying. I am sort of a newbie.

Comment: That's OK! Look into https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp a bit. It basically lets you call a function repeatedly. You have to change your code slightly so that there is a function for it to call repeatedly and so that the calls stop when you reach the target.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Also something else I'm have trouble with is setting the information I receive from the API to a variable. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: For getting the response see the info on this link https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp  Basically you want to use the `request.onreadystatechange` inside it you can check for errors then the object you want is `request.responseText`. Assign that to some global variable and then call your start timer function